# How can GeoJson polygons be colored programmatically using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, polygon, thematic-map, style

I'm experimenting with dynamically setting the color values of a geojson polygon. In my geojson file, there is an attribute for each polygon called `pop_den`. I am trying to update the `fillcolor` of the polygon base on the value of an attribute in the geojson file. I have a function `getColor()` that returns a color, based on the input value.

```
getColor = function (d) {

    return d > 35000 ? '#800026' :
           d > 30000 ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 25000 ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 20000 ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 15000 ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 10000 ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 5000  ? '#FED976' :
                       '#FFEDA0' ;
}
```

When I define my `StyleMap` I am attempting to call this function, so that the appropriate color is set, based on the value of this attribute for each polygon:

```
var myStyles = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ 
     "default": new OpenLayers.Style({ 
                        fillColor: "${getColor(pop_den)}",                         
                        strokeColor: "#00FF01", 
                        fillOpacity: 0.5, 
                        graphicZIndex: 1 
                    })
               });               

var geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {styleMap: myStyles});
```

This does not work, and I am not sure if it is possible to call a function from with the style file using `${getColor(pop_den)}`. I also tried `fillColor: getColor(pop_den)` but I get an error that `pop_den is not defined`. Can this approach work? I'm not clear on how the `StyleMap` works exactly when an argument is passed in using `${}`.

I am aware of more sophisticated ways of doing this using MapServer, but I am curious to test this approach using small amounts of data to understand what the pros/cons of this approach are.

Comment: http://crschmidt.net/mapping/choropleth.html is using rules based on attribution in the GeoJSON file.

Comment: I was also curious if there was a more concise way of achieving this, other than the rule definition as the code becomes extremely long, quickly.

Comment: I found a useful example here also that uses the approach that @Captdragon suggested: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/styles-context.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Placing it within a `context` should work. Something like this:

```
var myStyles = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ 
     "default": new OpenLayers.Style({ 
                fillColor: "${getColor}",                         
                strokeColor: "#00FF01", 
                fillOpacity: 0.5, 
                graphicZIndex: 1 

            },
            {
                context: {
                    getColor : function (feature) {
                        return feature.attributes.pop_den > 35000 ? '#800026' :
                               feature.attributes.pop_den > 30000 ? '#BD0026' :
                               feature.attributes.pop_den > 25000 ? '#E31A1C' :
                               feature.attributes.pop_den > 20000 ? '#FC4E2A' :
                               feature.attributes.pop_den > 15000 ? '#FD8D3C' :
                               feature.attributes.pop_den > 10000 ? '#FEB24C' :
                               feature.attributes.pop_den > 5000  ? '#FED976' :
                                                                    '#FFEDA0' ;
                    }
                } 
            })
       });               

var geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {styleMap: myStyles});
```

Comment: Thanks for the `context` suggestion. I tried `getColor: function (d) {return ...}` and although it is error free it does not change the `fillColor`.

Comment: Okay, I updated the code to work. What you need to do is store pop_den in a property of the feature like `feature.attribute.prop_den` (must be within `feature.attributes` to be read) so the context can see it. Also notice how I had the position of context wrong.. it needs to be in it's own object after the style attributes.

Comment: Thanks, that works and is very elegant. I suppose it is obvious, but the `getColor()` function can just call another external function too so long as it is returning a color.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: This works sweet! Is there also a way I could add a simple info window?

Comment: @StefanVanDerHoorn [simple info window example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html)

Comment: But how can I point to a geojson file. Is that also working with a getfeatureinfo request. My geojson layer is as follows 

var geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
    styleMap: myStyles,

                projection: epsg4326,

                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],

                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({

                    url: "pc2.geojson",

                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()

                })
            });

Comment: @StefanVanDerHoorn Please ask in a separate question.

Comment: @CaptDragon Thanks for you comment. I made an new question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42401/how-can-i-add-an-infowindow-to-an-openlayers-geojson-layer